# parse json in as2

Tags: json, actionscript-2

I need to load and parse some JSON in flash, AS2. The problem is the parsin. It seems that i cant get out what i want from the object. Its a one level object and below you can see how it looks like filled with some dummy text.

My JSON object looks like this:

```
[
{
    data    
},
{
    data
}
]
```

Now, how do i parse this in as2? And is it possible? I have only done it in as3 before.
I think what i need is some sort of code how to acually load and parse it in as2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this (just tested it with AS2, and seems to work):

http://inner.geek.nz/archives/2007/01/18/loading-json-in-actionscript-2/

http://web.archive.org/web/20111014093347/http://inner.geek.nz/uploads/JSON.as

Usage:

```
try {
  var o:Object = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
  var s:String = JSON.stringify(obj);
} catch(ex) {
  trace(ex.name + ":" + ex.message + ":" + ex.at + ":" + ex.text);
}
```